# Using IIS and windows credential to login

Tags: iis, credentials

on windows 2003, we have a CRM that we have built. i want the login to be with the logged in user on the computer.

when i remove the anonymous from the iis i get the popup for username and password.
when i try to log in with username and password it won't work unless i add the domain before the username.

my questions are:
1. can i have the user to enter only the username and not both with the domain?
2. after a login, is it possible to do logout?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What authentication method do you have enabled? Are the users and the web server in the same AD domain?

Comment: yes they are on the same AD domain.

Comment: there is no specefic for me. i want it to work like i have said above

Comment: I don't understand your second comment.